# Using rpm specfile to get files to be installed

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I'm looking for a solution to query an RPM spec file to get the lists of files it installs, preferably without building the package(s). I've tried `rpmspec --queryformat '%{filenames}'` but it only results in `(none)`

Example test.spec:

```
Name:           test
Version:        1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        test
License:        bsd
URL:            http://localhost
Source0:        test.tgz
%description
%install
%files
/usr/foo.txt
```

Test run:

```
$ rpmspec --builtrpms -q --qf 'name: %{name}\nfiles: %{filenames}\n\n' test.spec
name: test
files: (none)
```

Expected result:

```
name: test
files: /usr/foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec file doesn't know how many files are being installed.

If it had something like this:

```
%files
/path/to/a/ton/of/files/
```

there's no way for it to know how many files would be in that directory after building the software.

If you've built the RPM, you can use `rpm -qlp <rpmfile>` to see the files it *would* install without doing the actual installation. But again, you need a built RPM.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Since this project doesn't specify directories in the spec I can use some sed/awk instead.